# fetch the column from index and check that column are present in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Use recursive query to list out all Employees required for a particular Manager
WITH [EMP_cte]([BusinessEntityID], [OrganizationNode], [FirstName], [LastName], [JobTitle], [RecursionLevel]) -- CTE name and columns
AS (
    SELECT 
        e.[BusinessEntityID]
        , e.[OrganizationNode]
        , p.[FirstName]
        , p.[LastName]
        , e.[JobTitle]
        , 0 -- Get the initial Employee
    FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
    INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] as p
        ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
    WHERE e.[BusinessEntityID] = @BusinessEntityID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        e.[BusinessEntityID]
        , e.[OrganizationNode]
        , p.[FirstName]
        , p.[LastName]
        , e.[JobTitle]
        , [RecursionLevel] + 1 -- Join recursive member to anchor
    FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
    INNER JOIN [EMP_cte]
        ON e.[OrganizationNode] = [EMP_cte].[OrganizationNode].GetAncestor(1)
    INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] p 
        ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
)
-- Join back to Employee to return the manager name 
SELECT 
[EMP_cte].[RecursionLevel]
, [EMP_cte].[BusinessEntityID]
, [EMP_cte].[FirstName]
, [EMP_cte].[LastName]
, [EMP_cte].[OrganizationNode].ToString() AS [OrganizationNode]
, p.[FirstName] AS 'ManagerFirstName'
, p.[LastName] AS 'ManagerLastName'  -- Outer select from the CTE
FROM [EMP_cte] 
INNER JOIN [HumanResources].[Employee] e 
    ON [EMP_cte].[OrganizationNode].GetAncestor(1) = e.[OrganizationNode]
INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] p 
    ON p.[BusinessEntityID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
ORDER BY [RecursionLevel], [EMP_cte].[OrganizationNode].ToString()
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 25) 
END;
```

how to fetch the column from index and check that column are present in select statement or not in procedures

Comment: _"how to fetch the column from index"_ - what do you call "index" here and "fetch from index"?

Comment: @IvanStarostin  by index i mean any clustered or non-clustered index created on a table,by "fetch from index"  i mean that i want to check whether the column present in index is used in the select statement in the procedures.

Comment: You want to find something like list of dependencies? You have number of indexes with some columns indexes and you want to check whether these indexes/indexed columns are actually in use or these indexes are useless (so you can drop index or remove columns from it)? Correct?

Comment: @IvanStarostin,Thanks how can i check the dependencies for a procedures.

Comment: Google `ms sql find unused indexes`.